# Non-isolated input conditioning for a crude switch

Tags: esd, zener

I'm trying to build something Arduino-based which can (among other things) detect when a user touches two specific fingers together.  The best idea I can come up with is to have a wire on each finger that forms a circuit when they touch each other.  I'm afraid that some kind of static discharge or other accident applied to the wires could fry the Arduino.  I read that using a Zener diode attached to ground before the input would work but that it might not catch very fast spikes (as in the case of an ESD, I would presume).

Is there a better way to protect the chip from such circumstances?  Or better yet how can I improve my design so that this doesn't become an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I retagged your question as it's relevant for any microcontroller or sensitive IC.

Answer (score 4):

standard practice is both of the following:

- zener diode connected from outer input to ground
- small resistor connected from outer input to CPU pin (20-100ohms?)

The zener diode clamps outer input between (ground - Vbe diode drop, where Vbe = between 0.7-1.0V) and (ground + zener clamp voltage at high current). The small resistor helps limit current from outer input into CPU pin.

ESD-clamping diodes (more commonly known as TVS = [transient voltage suppressors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient%5Fvoltage%5Fsuppressor); tons of companies make them, good mfrs are [ON Semi](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/parametrics.do?id=824) and [Diodes Inc](http://www.diodes.com/products/catalog/list.php?parent-id=46) and [Fairchild](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/sitesearch/fsc.jsp?command=eq&attr1=AAAFamily&attr2=Transient+Voltage+Suppressor+%28TVS%29)) are really just zener diodes optimized for this use, that can handle high surge power w/o getting damaged. If you are concerned (or if you are working on a commercial product), I'd use one of them, but a regular zener will almost certainly work.

Make sure you use minimum wire/lead length from outer input to ground: the more inductance you introduce in series with the clamping diode, the worse it will perform.

(*NOTE*: regular zeners add capacitance, maybe a few hundred pF. If you have a communication line or other circuit node which is sensitive to capacitance, you'll need a special clamping diode that is designed for low-capacitance. These usually have the following topology internal to the part:

```
*-----+--->Z------|<------+------*
      |                   |
      +------>|-----------+

 -->Z--   = zener
 -->|--   = regular diode
```

The regular diode in series with the zener reduces the capacitance, and you then need another diode in parallel with those two, in order to clamp in the other direction.)

Comment: So, like this?
http://i.imgur.com/mdK0b.png
I'm pretty sure I need to add a resistor in there somewhere but I'm not sure where...?
Also do you know where to buy one of these optimized "ESD clamping diodes"?  Maybe I'm not searching for the right thing.

Comment: they're called TVS (transient voltage suppressors) -- I had a brain blank when writing the above stuff. will fix, thanks.

Comment: in your sketch, put a resistor between the switch and the TVS.

Comment: Okay, so I mentioned my project on IRC and someone gave me the following advice: "<HTT-Bird> yeah, a switch line, use 1n4148s to GND and VCC with a 100nF cap bypassing the rails, a series resistor in the line too helps <HTT-Bird> like 10ohm or something <HTT-Bird> keep the diodes from getting completely shot" - Is this equivalent, or does it behave differently? Also I'm having trouble finding a 3.3v TVS that I can mount on my ProtoShield, do those exist? Thanks for your help!

Comment: not quite the same. what httbird is talking about is clamping the voltage to the power rails. That's ok, but I'd use Schottky diodes rather than 1N4148s: they are faster and have lower on-state voltage. The bypass cap helps prevent voltage spikes on the power rails; if you care about it, add a 4V zener or something across the power rails. Should be a high enough voltage so leakage current is minimal at the high end of your power supply spec, but not much higher than that.

Answer (score 3):

A circuit like sketched below shurly will work too.
The two diodes clamp the voltage against VCC and GND and the Resistor limits the current

```
------------------------*-------- VCC
                        | 
                    ---
                      ^
                       / \
                       ---
             ----       |
Ext Input --|    |------*-------- Arduino Input
             ----       |
             10k        |
                   ---
                     ^
                    / \
                    ---
              |
------------------------*-------- GND
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a capacitive sense IC like the Atmel Q-touch devices.

In general for transient suppression I would use a transient voltage suppressor (TVS) with
a series current limiting resistor. I like the Littefuse SP-7xx devices. Very fast.